# counting COUNT(*) results in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to count the number of records returned from a MySQL query.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(sa.facility_hmis) AS deployed
FROM
    facility_service_area sa
GROUP BY sa.facility_hmis
```

this will give me lets say 6 rows as the result, but i need it to give me a single row with just the number counted rows i.e 6

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [distinct](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct facility_hmis) AS deployed FROM facility_service_area
```

Answer (score 3):

If all you need is to count number of distinct `facility_hmis` you can do that explicitly, without counting of anything else:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT facility_hmis) FROM facility_service_area
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the query in another `count()`

```
SELECT COUNT(1) from (
  SELECT COUNT(sa.facility_hmis) AS deployed FROM facility_service_area sa GROUP BY sa.facility_hmis
)
```